# reCAPTCHA v3: g-recaptcha-response is outsite the form

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

With this example of reCAPTCHA v3, the g-recaptcha-response textarea is outsite the form...

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onloadCallback = function() {
            console.log('onloadCallback');

            grecaptcha.execute(
                "SITEKEY",
                {action: "homepage"})
                .then(function(token) {
                        console.log('verifyCallback')
                        console.log(token);
                    }
                );

        };
    </script>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=SITEKEY&onload=onloadCallback"></script>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

So there's no `$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]`

What adjustments are necessary to provide the textarea inside the form tags?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need the hidden input in your form that receives the response and you also need to set the token to the hidden input value

```
<input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="" />

document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
```

However, I'm also having issues with the recaptcha v.3 implementation in Magento 2.